# How to check if a path fits inside of another path with Extendscript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I've asked this question in the Adobe forums, but I haven't gotten an answer yet, I'm afraid. If this is truly impossible, then shame on Adobe for not making it possible.

I need a script that will check and see if a path fits **entirely** within another path. In my case, I need to see if a `GroupItem` fits within a circle/ellipse of a specific size. I don't see any methods available for `PageItem` that will do it for me, so does anyone know of a workaround? (Preferably without having to check every single `PathPoint` of every single item in the group.) I am using Illustrator CS6 and do my scripting with Javascript.

I am aware of the `visibleBounds` property of paths, but that only gives you a top, bottom, left, and right maximum boundaries of a path. It's entirely possible for an object's `visibleBounds` to be within an ellipse's `visibleBounds`, but still have parts of it sticking outside of the ellipse. I hope this makes sense and that someone out there has an idea on how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not overly familiar with Illustrator, but does it have a path to selection function similar to Photoshop?  I've used that to achieve similar to this.  Essentially:

1. convert your internal path as a selection
2. subtract the selection based on the outer path from the selection created in step 1
3. if you don't have any selection left, the internal path is completely
   contained within the outer selection